# How does Encoding.Convert work?

Tags: c#, encoding

We are storing data in a searchable format, optimised for speed. We want to replace non-basic characters  like é with e etc. so we have a-z 1-9

We found we could do this using `Encoding.Convert` and ansi1252 but not all characters are supported, e.g. russian characters: ã would become a but russian В would become ?.

What we need is to be able to explain to the user of the service exactly which characters are OK and which are not. Or if possible, use a better method of converting.

For this, I need to understand how `Encoding.Convert` converts between the two. But I can't find any information on google. Does anyone know where I might look?

Comment: You can check [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoder.cs,269421dd52c20941). But I really don't see a problem to implement dictionary replace, because it's *your rules* and you are free to change them.

Comment: I think you should rather implement something like [Lucene's ASCIIFoldingFilter](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_3_0_3_RC2_final/src/core/Analysis/ASCIIFoldingFilter.cs).

Comment: Doing it myself is a bit tricky because there are so many possible unicode characters. I was hoping for maybe an ISO standard for conversion